# Difference between gnome-shell & ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Tags: gnome, package-management, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit). Now I want to install Gnome Desktop Environment (without removing unity). I know I can install by following command:

1. `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`
2. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

But I don't know exact difference between them. (may be i've misunderstanding with them)

So, **What is difference between installing Gnome by `gnome-shell` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`?**

And Which should I use to install Gnome Desktop Environment?

Comment: Gnome Shell, would be installing a vanilla Gnome3 desktop whereas Ubuntu-Gnome-Desktop is the pre-configured DE that come installed in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. In the end, they both install a pretty vanilla experience, but both should install Gnome3 DE, then just switch to it at the login screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ubuntu-gnome-desktop` will install a full GNOME desktop environment (including `gnome-shell`), along with a few standard applications and optimizations for Ubuntu.

`gnome-shell` will only install the GNOME shell, and its dependencies. In contrast to `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, it won't install the package `gnome-session` (among others) automatically, which you need to actually use the GNOME desktop.

So, to get the desktop environment, you should install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

---

Following will cleraly show that `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` depends on `gnome-shell` so it includes the package `gnome-shell`:

```
$ apt-cache depends ubuntu-gnome-desktop | grep gnome-shell
  Depends: gnome-shell
  Depends: gnome-shell-extensions
```

Comment: What good is the `gnome-shell` package if it does not work without `gnome-session`?

Answer (score 0):

gnome-shell only installs the desktop enviorment, while ubunut-gnome-desktop is a group of packages that contains gnome-shell and all of the basic ubuntu gnome application like totem, rhytmbox, firefox....